# Azure Stream Analytics - Reference Blob not found

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics, azure-data-factory

I am having a hard time setting up Stream Analytics to use a reference Blob.

I have Data factory moving a table from SQL table to a CSV file in a blob container. I did try the data/time method but could not get that to work at all coming up with the following error.

Initializing input without a valid reference data blob for UTC time

After I couldnt get that to work, I just had the Factory put the CSV into the base folder. So the container is "companyname" and folder is "referencedata" with a file name "DeviceRef.csv".

The Stream Analytics job has the all the details of the storage account with the container as "companyname" and the Path Pattern: /referencedata/DeviceRef.csv but coming up with an error saying "Specified Blob does not exist". When I test the location in Stream Analytics, it comes up saying successful.

Any help with this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I found out what the issue was.

I had the Path Pattern: /referencedata/DeviceRef.csv

There should be no "/" at the front of the path. Deleted and works.